# Using external Python libraries. How do other programmers run my code?

Tags: python

I need to use an external Python library (available from Github) in my own Python code.

How do I ensure both myself and other developers (who clone my repo) can execute my code, which calls the external library?

Do I just `git clone` the external library to a path within my repo and then `import` the library directory from my code?

And this would allow another dev to clone my repo and run my code (including the external library) with no problems?

Nobody has to run a package installer?

Comment: can't you just use a `requirements.txt` file and specify the package there?

Comment: If the external library isn't available with pip you can use try using git submodules.

Comment: @gold_cy I don't code Python often. I'm unsure if I (and any other users need to run pip), or if I can just clone the libs in to my repo and this will allow all of us to run the code. This is effectively my question- how can we all run the code which requires external Python libraries?

Comment: @PasiÖsterman So I don't git clone the library in to my repo, I install them on my machine and any machine wishing to run my code, using pip?

Comment: If you've installed the library using pip then you can use requirements.txt like mentioned by gold_cy.  This file basically includes list of all the dependencies required to run your project and can be fed to pip to install said dependencies.

Comment: @PasiÖsterman I haven't installed the library (yet). My question is, do I need to install the library? This might seem stupid/obvious but I wasn't sure if I could use it without installing it, by cloning the source code in to my repo to use?

Comment: If you want to use the library you need to install the library using package manager like pip. If you want to provide easy way for others to know which packages your project depends upon you can write requirements.txt that should list all the external packages and their versions your project needs in order to work.  Check if the library is available in  [pypi](https://pypi.org/)

Comment: @PasiÖsterman Yes, understood now. If you put it as an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Installing packages

If you want to use package in python you need to install it using [pip package manager](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/). You can do so using command `python -m pip install <packageName>`

#### Install scope

By default python installs packages with **global scope** which means that they're available for all python scripts (unless a virtual environment is in use).

When dealing with multiple python projects one can use [virtual environments (VENV)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to avoid version conflicts and whatnot. This however is a bit more advanced and involved practice which might be a bit of an overkill if you're just looking to write a small script to test or automate something.

#### Sharing project

When sharing your project or script you list the packages it depends upon using using text file typically named [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#requirements-files). This allows other developers to install dependencies listed in the file using single command: `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` which then allows them to run the project.